# PHP preg_match Regular Expression Improvement

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

**Hello All**,

I am trying to widen the scope on a **preg_match** I currently use in a shoutbox. I am struggling to build on my current regular expression to obtain the desired identification. Please see the current regex I am using followed by some information on the matches I would like to achieve.

---

**Current regular expression:**

`~\bf+(?:\.+|\s+)?r+(?:\.+|\s+)?e+(?:\.+|\s+)?d+(?:\.+|)?\b~i`

**Desired match info:**

[01] Lorem ipsum dolor **fred** sit amet.

- *Identify key word*.

[02] Lorem ipsum dolor **$fred** sit amet.

- *Identify single dollar symbol and key word.*

[03] Lorem ipsum dolor **$ofred** sit amet.

- *Identify single dollar symbol followed by a single alphanumeric character and key word.*

[04] Lorem ipsum dolor **$ooofred** sit amet.

- *Identify single dollar symbol followed by multiple alphanumeric characters and key word.*

[05] Lorem ipsum dolor **$$$ooofred** sit amet.

- *Identify multiple dollar symbols followed by multiple alphanumeric characters and key word.*

[06] Lorem ipsum dolor **$$$ofred** sit amet.

- *Identify multiple dollar symbols followed by a single alphanumeric character and key word.*

[07] Lorem ipsum dolor **$o$oo$$$ofred** sit amet.

- *Identify any combination of dollar symbols and alphanumeric characters followed by key word.*

[08] Lorem ipsum dolor $o$oo **$$$ofred** sit amet.

- *Spaces break the identification*

[09] **$ofred** sit amet.

- *Identified with no leading spaces*

[10] Lorem ipsum dolor **$ofred**

- *Identified with no trailing spaces*

[11] Lorem ipsum dolor **$ofred**!

- *Identified with trailing symbols*

---

Thank you for any help, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be the longest explanation I have ever seen for a regex that is so small:

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=^|\s)(?:\bfred\b|\$[$\w]*fred\b)/x', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
"
(?<=           # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
               # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      ^        # Assert position at the beginning of the string
   |           # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      \s       # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
)
(?:            # Match the regular expression below
               # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      \b       # Assert position at a word boundary
      fred     # Match the characters “fred” literally
      \b       # Assert position at a word boundary
   |           # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      \$       # Match the character “$” literally
      [$\w]    # Match a single character present in the list below
               # The character “$”
               # A word character (letters, digits, etc.)
         *     # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      fred     # Match the characters “fred” literally
      \b       # Assert position at a word boundary
)
"
```

Comment: [Red Face] I guess I'm not the best at explaining things :) Thank you very much though, your answer seems to do the job brilliantly. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Matthew Stand by, for editing. I am improving it. There may be some cases I omitted :)

Comment: @Matthew The now edited regex matches **exactly** what you asked for. Nothing less/nothing more. You are welcome btw :)

Comment: Thanks for the revision, is there any chance of allowing space(s) in the key word, i.e. fred in this case?

Comment: That would be a very different more complex regex. Everything is possible though. But you should probably open another question for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
/((\$[\w\$]*)?fred)/
```

What's wrong with that regex?

I'm not sure I understand the significance of:

```
(?:\.+|\s+)
```

In your regex.

Comment: This fails with fredy Krueger! And you don't want that to happen :)